# AlertDialog with ArrayAdapter not showing list of items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to create an `AlertDialog` that will display a list of a custom object `Supplier`. The `toString()` method has been overridden to display a description.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExampleActivity.this);
dialog.setTitle("Title");
dialog.setMessage("Message:");

final ArrayAdapter<Supplier> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Supplier>(
        ExampleActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);

adapter.add(new Supplier());
adapter.add(new Supplier());
adapter.add(new Supplier());

dialog.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
dialog.show();
```

From the examples I have looked at, I can't find anything obviously wrong with this code. However, when I run it, it doesn't show a list of the supplier objects as expected. I've also tried using the `setItems` and `setSingleChoiceItems` methods for the `AlertDialog.Builder`. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out you can't set a message and an adapter together. It works when I remove `dialog.setMessage("Message:")`.

Comment: Any idea why they can't go together?

Comment: I think it was a design choice more than anything. They are mutually exclusive so you can only use one or the other. A way around it is to create a layout with a TextView and a ListView, inflate it, do what you want to do with it and use the setView method. The problem I found with that method though is that the ListView will sometimes appear off screen if the list is large. So you may need to give it a fixed height. Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, I just spent the last hour screaming at my computer over this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.logobig);
builderSingle.setTitle("");

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
  context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
);

arrayAdapter.add("Customer 1 ");
arrayAdapter.add("Customer 2");

builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    switch (which) {
      case 0:
        // handle item1
      break;
      case 1:
        // item2
      break;
      case 2:
        // item3
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }
  }
});

builderSingle.show();
```